# How to deal with functions returning a either monad

Tags: haskell, monads

I am trying to incorporate error handling in my code.

I am calling a function

```
generateCSR :: (MonadRandom m, HashAlgorithmConversion hashAlg, HashAlgorithm hashAlg) 
            => X520Attributes -> PKCS9Attributes -> KeyPair -> hashAlg 
            -> m (Either Error CertificationRequest)
```

So I need to handle the error in this case. I assumed I could do something like this

```
case generateCSR (parameters) of
 Right req -> req
 left Error -> putStrLn ("Error : " ++ show Error)
```

But this doesn't seem to work.

But if I do something like this

```
 Right req <- generateCSR (parameters)
 putStrLn.show req
```

it gives me an output.

How can I implement the error handling here? Am I doing something completely wrong in the first case (the `case of` statement) ?

Comment: What do you want to do with the Right value? In this case, it looks like you have to converge the types into a single one, something like: `f :: Either Error CertificationRequest -> IO ()` or the like.

Comment: So The function I am writing should Either Return a Certificate Request or an Error ,

Comment: The second snippet is a part of a `do` block, which implicitly involves `>>=` for the monad at hand. The `case` instead does not use `>>=` or monads. In general, these constructs are very different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure how you can pass a single `parameters` to `generateCSR` since it wants 4 arguments, but I'll chalk it up to pseudocode.

`generateCSR` returns an `Either` wrapped in some monand `m`, which must be an instance of `MonadRandom`, of which `IO` is a candidate.  You cannot directly use a case on the result; you must use the monad's bind to access the `Either` within.  In your second example, you used bind with a pattern that requires the `Either` to be `Right`, which will not gracefully handle the case that it is `Left`.  Instead, you can bind the result to a variable and then use a case statement to decide what to do:

```
f = do
    r <- generateCSR parameters
    case r of
        Left err -> ...
        Right req -> ...
```

Note that both cases will also have to return something wrapped in the same monad, as required by `do` (bind).